# Azure purge cdn via api authentication process 401

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to purge the cache via the azure api.

1. I have created an Azure Active Directory / App Registration called "Purge CDN APP".

**Permissions:**

Windows Azure Active Directory / Delegated Permissions / Sign in and read user profile

Windows Azure Service Management API / Delegated Permissions / Access Azure Service Management as organization users (preview)

**Keys:**
I have created a key. I entered a in guid and it return a secret key. I'm using this as my client secret.

2. I have an end point "CDN endpoint". I have added a contributor "Purge CDN APP"

**I'm able to generate a token. However, i am getting a 401 error. There are quite a few steps here. Are you able to pinpoint where i have gone wrong. The client id i'm using is from the app registration application id.**

```
   private static string GetAccessTokenAndMakePurgeCall()
   {
            var subscriptionId = "xxxxx-xxxx-4dd7-8fec-ad3cd882b066";
            var resourceGroup = "xxxHosting";
            var profileName = "nameofcdn";
            var endpointName = "nameofendpoint"; 
            var apiVersion = "2016-10-02";
            var url = string.Format(
                "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/{2}/endpoints/{3}/purge?api-version={4}", 
                subscriptionId,
                resourceGroup,
                profileName,
                endpointName,
                apiVersion);


            string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"];
            string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"];
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com");
            ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
            Task<AuthenticationResult> resultstr = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential);

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var token = resultstr.Result.AccessToken;
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + token);
            client.Headers.Add(string.Format("api-version:{0}", apiVersion));
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

            var bodyText = "{\"ContentPaths\":[\"/*\"]}";

            try
            {
                var result = client.UploadString(url, bodyText);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ew)
            {
                return ew.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Giving permissions on *Windows Azure Service Management API* is not needed.

Comment: I assume `https://login.microsoftonline.com/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com` is not your actual authority? :)